# Ping request timed out when basehttpserver is loading website

Tags: php, python, http-headers

I am running a website using basehttpserver. 10.0.xx.xx is the ip to access the site. There is a 'controller' with a cellular modem on it, which hosts the website and runs the basehttpserver.

When loading a simple website, just a 22kb image file (locally hosted) - all ping request time out while this image / webpage is loading. When it's done, the ping becomes successful again.

The original website was far more complex, but I narrowed it down to it happening even with a simple website like this. Also, when I run tracert it fails on the last hop (please see last image).

Can anyone offer any insight to why this might be happening? And if I should be worried about it?

I've looked into changing the php/http headers (with no luck), and hosting the website externally on an IIS server (it loads just fine, no ping issues) - so I know it's something to do with the basehttpserver... but other than that I'm a bit out of my depth. Many thanks.

PHP DOC (status.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="image22kb.jpg" style="width:640px; height:auto;"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ping

[CMD: Ping IP address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk8W8.jpg)

TRACERT

[CMD: Tracert (fails on last hop, original IP)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHErh.jpg)

Comment: I didn't have enough rep points to post a 3rd link, but here are my http headers: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hc3Zh.jpg

Comment: Could you add some details about the network setup you are using ? You mention this runs across a "cellular modem", what specific type of connection is it ? Are you potentially running out of bandwidth because of a qos configuration ? You might try pinging with a higher timeout (-w option for windows' ping) to see if you are not getting a response at all, or if it's just taking too long to respond.

Comment: Thanks. It's a 3G cellular modem, broadcasting through a wifi router. The connection is made over wifi (not ethernet). I tried setting the ping cmd to a high timeout - IE: `ping -w 20000 10.0.xx.xx` and it never timed out, although some very very slow (over 4000ms) - so I'm guessing this suggests this is a hardware / bandwidth issue?

Comment: To me it does at any rate. Are you sure your 3G modem is actually getting a good 3G signal ? Could it be degrading to GPRS/Edge which has very low bandwidth ? How long does the 22KB file take to download ?